# Python does not work anymore after update of django and python update

Tags: python, django

I have python code for my website.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13
./manage.py --version
1.11.11
```

Everything was working well before an update of my server. One function have to read into a file where I have something like:

```
1,"TY - JOUR|T1 - BLABLABLA|.........|AU - name1|AU - name2|......"
```

I use the following python code:

```
from django.db import models
.....

class Sources(models.Model):
    sourceid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ris = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'sources'

    def extractChain(self,tokens,st):
        for token in tokens:
            if(token.startswith(st)): break

        result = token[5:]

        if(st == "TY"):
            result={
                "JOUR": "journal",
                "BOOK": "book",
                "":""
            }[result]

        return result

    def author(self,tokens,st):
        a=[]
        for token in tokens:
           if(token.startswith(st)): a.append(token[5:])
        return a

    def extractRisVal(self,st):
        tokens = self.ris.split("|")
        result={
            "TY": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "T1": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "JO": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "VL": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "IS": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "SP": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "EP": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "PY": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "AU": self.author(tokens,st),
            "M1": self.extractChain(tokens,st),
            "ER": self.extractChain(tokens,st)
        }[st]

        return result
```

`Source.sourceid` gives 1. That's ok. But when I use the method `extractRisVal(self,st)` like:

```
extractRisVal("TY")
```

it literrally returns `extractRisVal("TY")` while it should be `journal`.

If I add a test method in the Source class:

```
def testCode(self):
    a=[]
    tokens = self.ris.split("|")
    for token in tokens:
        if(token.startswith("AU")): a.append(token[5:])
    return a
```

It returns what I want. So it looks like I have a problem with the attributes token and st in the method argument. Because each time I want to use it, it does not work.

Comment: This code is very strange. Why do you call extractChain so many  times with the same arguments?

Comment: I'm not the first writer of this code. So I have to deal with it. extractChain is only called for each type of token we can found.

Comment: No it isn't. It's called ten times with exactly the same argument.

Comment: Well, probably beyond my Python skills. Thanks.

Comment: But if I define tokens = self.ris.split("|") outside from testCode, in the classe Source. And then if I add token in testCode arguments. It does not work. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this could be start another virtual env or conda env with previous versions and try running the code again.

Comment: For other parts of the code I need this version. This is why I've updated everything.